# PHP Array from URL param not behaving as expected

Tags: php

I have a URL parameter containing category IDs that I want to treat as an array which looks like this:

```
http://example.com?cat[]=3,9,13
```

In PHP I am using this to get the array from the URL parameter:

```
$catIDs = $_GET['cat'];
```

When I do an echo `gettype($catIDs);` it shows that it is in fact being treated as an array, but when I do a `print_r($catIDs);` I am getting this:

```
Array ([0] => 3,9,13)
```

But I am expecting this:

```
Array ([0] => 3, [1] => 9, [2] => 13)
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not on the server/PHP side, it's on the client/request side. The given URL gives you an array containing one element, a comma-separated string:

```
cat[]=3,9,13
```

Yields:

```
["3,9,13"]
```

To specify an array via URL parameters, you need to repeat the parameter name for each item:

```
cat[]=3&cat[]=9&cat[]=13
```

Yields:

```
["3","9","13"]
```

Alternately, you could specify a single parameter that's comma-separated:

```
cat=3,9,13
```

And then just split it:

```
$cat = explode(',', $_GET['cat']);
```

Comment: Thanks! So in order to get what I want from the existing parameter structure, I'm assuming I would just convert the array to a string and then use `explode()` to get it back to an array?

Comment: If you can't change the way the URL is called, then, rather than "convert the array to a string," I'd just take the first element out of the array and then explode that: `explode(',', $_GET['cat'][0]);`

Comment: You'd then have to ask yourself what to do in case the caller sends more than one set: `cat[]=1,2,3&cat[]=4,5,6`